# background-image in mean.js

Tags: css, mean

I tried to include a background image on my landing page. My CSS file is here:

/modules/core/css/core.css

My image file is here:

/modules/core/img/image.jpg

In the css file I tried doing this:

background-image: url("../img/image.jpg");

I also tried doing this:

background-image: url("core/img/image.jpg");

However, none of them are working or the solutions I looked at this site for other similar questions. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

if CSS `/modules/core/css/core.css` and image is `/modules/core/img/image.jpg`,
background need be `background-image: url("../img/image.jpg");` but are you sure is **jpg** or **JPG**, sometimes this can be bug :)

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but, I am not seeing the image. The image had a jpeg extension when downloaded first and that was changed to jpg. I am not exactly sure about the difference between jpeg and jpg...

Comment: maybe you don't have same name  Image and image not same :)

Comment: I had to use z-index, instead of the above. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab in inspector to see what happens when the browser tried to load the image. What do you get in the status column?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.